# Laravel | Unable to get results of matching substrings

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, search

Question :

I have a table called `product` with some bunch of columns. One of which is `name`. The problem is :

**Sample entries:**

1. name: Salt Powder.
2. name: Chilli powdeR

**The problem**

When i do a query for  `https://example.com/public/api/products?search=name%3Apowder`  **I get 0 results** .

**Expectation is to return**

Salt Powder & Chilli powdeR since the term "powder" is common in both.

Now when i do a query for `https://example.com/public/api/products?search=name%3Asalt+powder` , i get `Salt powder` as the result.

Here's my `controller` & what i have been trying to implement in the index :

```
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
     
     if (Query::has('search')) {              ------>>> I know that something is terribly wrong here.
        $queryString = Query::get('search');
        $products = Products::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$queryString%")->orderBy('name')->paginate(5);
    }   
        try{
            $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($request));
            $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new LimitOffsetCriteria($request));
            $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new ProductsOfFieldsCriteria($request));
            if($request->get('trending',null) == 'week'){
                $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new TrendingWeekCriteria($request));
            }
            else{
                $this->productRepository->pushCriteria(new NearCriteria($request));
            }

            $products = $this->productRepository->all();

        } catch (RepositoryException $e) {
            return $this->sendError($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $this->sendResponse($products->toArray(), 'Products retrieved successfully');
    }
```

My `productRepository.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Models\Product;
use InfyOm\Generator\Common\BaseRepository;
use Prettus\Repository\Contracts\CacheableInterface;
use Prettus\Repository\Traits\CacheableRepository;

    class ProductRepository extends BaseRepository implements CacheableInterface
    {
    
        use CacheableRepository;
        /**
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fieldSearchable = [
            'name',
            'seokeywords',
            'price',
            'discount_price',
            'description',
            'capacity',
            'package_items_count',
            'unit',
            'itemsAvailable',
            'featured',
            'store_id',
            'category_id',
            'brand_id'
        ];
    
        /**
         * Configure the Model
         **/
        public function model()
        {
            return Product::class;
        }
    
        /**
         * get my products
         **/
        public function myProducts()
        {
            return Product::join("user_stores", "user_stores.store_id", "=", "products.store_id")
                ->where('user_stores.user_id', auth()->id())->get();
        }
    }
```

Can someone please help to understand what or which statement should i modify ? I've tried changes but most attempts ended in errors. Any help is much appreciated. I can share any files that you guys may be interested to peak into

Comment: I guess you need to correct your wild card search clause to `where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$queryString.'%')`

Comment: But i'm getting syntax error at line     if (Query::has('search')) {   
        $queryString = Query::get('search') . Looking at the index above, what should be added instead of "Query" from which i could check if the term keyword is present . Can you please help ?

Comment: is "name:" part of the data stored in the db?

Comment: @Rabah : Yes sir, it is. To be specific, its a column within the table "product"

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear: is the data stored in the "name" column as: "Salt Powder" or as : "name: Salt Powder"

Comment: Oh, that saved under the "name" column as "Salt powder"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$request->query` to get the query string, and because you have "name:" included in it, you need to extract the search term:

```
if ($queryString = $request->query('search')) {
    [$column, $term] = explode(':', $queryString);

    $products = Products::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$term}%")
        ->orderBy('name')
        ->paginate(5);
}
```

note: aren't you missing an else clause? you seem to be overriding the $products variable.